# JPA "contains one of"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm writing a Dao to fetch all `Messages` relevant to a `Person`.  But I can't find the correct JPQL syntax.

In my model:

- a `Person` has multiple `Roles` (I pass these into the query as a parameter: Set of enum values).
- a `Message` is relevant to multiple `Roles`.

So I want to find all messages relevant to a person:

```
SELECT m FROM Message m
WHERE m.roles [contains one of] :userRoles
```

Giving it `:userRoles` as a `Set<Role>` parameter.

**What is the correct syntax for that missing [contains one of] section?**

I've looked at `IN` and `MEMBER OF`
e.g.

```
SELECT m FROM MESSAGE m
WHERE m.roles IN :userRoles
```

But both those keywords require a *single* item on one side. I have *multiple* items on *both* sides.

More detail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING)
    @JoinTable(name="message_roles",
        joinColumns={@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="message_id")})
    @Column(name="role_code")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    ...
}

public enum Role {
    DEVELOPER, ADMIN, TESTER, MANAGER
}
```

This produces a correct-looking table structure of:

```
message
    message_id

message_roles
    message_id
    role_code
```

But I can't work out how to query it to see if it contains one of a specific list of given roles.

Must I rewrite it to pass each of the user's roles in individually?

For application-specific reasons I can't join anywhere to get their roles: the roles must be a parameter of the query.

Comment: @Gimby there is no entity for Role: it's just mapped as an enum. I think that might be the root of my problem. The Roles are simply `private Set<Role> roles` in the `Message`

Comment: `[contains one of]` -> `IN` :)

Comment: @Hackerman good point: I guess "[intersects]" might be better.  I did have a look at using the `INTERSECT` keyword, but didn't get very far with that approach either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m FROM MESSAGE m JOIN m.roles r WHERE r IN :userRoles
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way that worked too:

```
SELECT m FROM Message m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM m.roles r WHERE r IN (:userRoles))
```