# Is there anyway in spring jpa to combine the "contain" and "or" semantic(contains one of) in a query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to provide a simple search api for my application. The api has an signature like:

```java
List<Blog> search(List<String> keywords);
```

It accept a keyword list and return all the blogs which title contains anyone of the keyword list.

Generally, on the db side i want to implement semantic like:

```sql
select * from blog where blog.title like `%keyword1` or blog.title like `%keyword2` or ...
```

The sql has variadic length.

Is there anyway in spring jpa to accomplish this?

---

I've read post like: [JPA "contains one of"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072771/jpa-contains-one-of), but it is different from what i need, since i want string contains but not "in".

Comment: There isn't even anything in SQL to accomplish that, but you can use a criteria query to build it dynamically from your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex instead with keywords joined as pattern:

```
String pattern = String.join("|", keywords);
pattern = String.format(".*(%s)", pattern);
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE blog.title REGEXP `pattern`
```